# How can I fix this WordPress fatal error issue?

Tags: php, wordpress

This is the message it is showing. I don't have no clue on how to solve it.

> Warning: require_once(): phar "/home/adrgscom/public_html/license.txt"
> SHA1 signature could not be verified: broken signature in
> /home/adrgscom/public_html/license.txt on line 110
>
> Warning:
> require_once(php://...@B@B@B@B@B@B@B@B@B@B@B4i@B@B@B@B@B@B0k@B@B@B@B@B@B@B@B@B@B5a@B@B.g@B@B@B):
> failed to open stream: operation failed in
> /home/adrgscom/public_html/license.txt on line 110
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
> 'php://...@B@B@B@B@B@B@B@B@B@B@B4i@B@B@B@B@B@B0k@B@B@B@B@B@B@B@B@B@B5a@B@B.g@B@B@B'
> (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php74/usr/share/pear') in
> /home/adrgscom/public_html/license.txt on line 110

Comment: As you haven't shared a single line of code, it's impossible to provide help. But requiring a text file in PHP sounds pretty strange

Comment: I have no clue what you want to say through that comment. Please keep in mind that all clarification should be added to your question by editing it

Comment: This looks suspiciously like your site has been compromised. You need to delete the whole thing, restore a safe data backup to a new install, and then audit what you have that night be vulnerable, e.g. outdated or badly written plugins and themes.

Comment: Can you provide more details? E.g., when does it happen? By what action? *Where* does the error message appear (where is the error message shown)? What kind of hosting (for example, [shared hosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_web_hosting_service) or by [WordPress.com](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress.com))? When did it happen? How long was the site up for before this happened (or is it only local development (has never been public))? What versions of WordPress and PHP?